# vb.net Change the Yvalue from a dataPoint inside a Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, datapoint

I have a realy sshort question.

How can you Change the y value from a DataPoint.
i know how to manualy set the y value.
i just go to Chart2 > Series > Series1 > Points and there they are DataPoints
I added 19 points so i was wondering how i can make it so when i press a button
then DataPoint 0 the Yvalue is Textbox1.text etc

i tought it would be something like

```
chart2.series("Dagloon").Point.DataPoint.Yvalue = textbox1.text
```

but that doesnt realy work.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart2.series("Dagloon").Point.DataPoint.Yvalue(0) = textbox1.text
```

Convert `textbox1.text` to `double`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Chart2.Series("Dagloon").Points.AddY(Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.text))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants because this adds a new x point but doesn't set "DataPoint 0 (ie. x point 0) the Yvalue".